# JS reformatting array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, object

I have an array object in this pattern.

```js
[
  {student_code: "AAA-001-ZYrq", questions: "Height (in cm)", answer: "4543435", time: "00:00:07:00"},
  {student_code: "AAA-001-6Yj8", questions: "Height (in cm)", answer: "4334", time: "00:00:02:32"},
  {student_code: "AAA-001-ZYrq", questions: "Weight (in kg)", answer: "2345", time: "00:00:01:999"},
  {student_code: "AAA-001-6Yj8", questions: "Weight (in kg)", answer: "34", time: "00:00:04:969"}
]
```

I want to reduce of reformat it by student_code and store the values in an array.

```js
{
  student_code: "AAA-001-ZYrq",
  questions: [
    {
      question: "Height (in cm)",
      answer: "4543435",
      time: "00:00:07:00"
    },
    {
      question: "Weight (in kg)",
      answer: "2345",
      time: "00:00:01:999"
    }
  ]
}
```

hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a `Map` of `student_code` to questions array, then transform that `Map` into your final array result

```js
// Polyfill
Map.prototype.computeIfAbsent = function(key, mappingFunction) {
  if (this.has(key)) {
    return this.get(key)
  }
  return this.set(key, mappingFunction(key)).get(key)
}

// The array from your question (minified)
const arr = [{"student_code":"AAA-001-ZYrq","questions":"Height (in cm)","answer":"4543435","time":"00:00:07:00"},{"student_code":"AAA-001-6Yj8","questions":"Height (in cm)","answer":"4334","time":"00:00:02:32"},{"student_code":"AAA-001-ZYrq","questions":"Weight (in kg)","answer":"2345","time":"00:00:01:999"},{"student_code":"AAA-001-6Yj8","questions":"Weight (in kg)","answer":"34","time":"00:00:04:969"}]

// Create a map of `student_code` to questions array
const studentMap = arr.reduce((map, { student_code, questions: question, ...other }) => {
  const questions = map.computeIfAbsent(student_code, () => [])
  questions.push({ question, ...other})
  return map
}, new Map())

// Transform to the final result
const result = Array.from(studentMap, ([ student_code, questions ]) => ({
  student_code,
  questions
}))

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height:100% !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement that structure using `Array.reduce` function.

```
const inputValue = [
  {student_code: "AAA-001-ZYrq", questions: "Height (in cm)", answer: "4543435", time: "00:00:07:00"},
  {student_code: "AAA-001-6Yj8", questions: "Height (in cm)", answer: "4334", time: "00:00:02:32"},
  {student_code: "AAA-001-ZYrq", questions: "Weight (in kg)", answer: "2345", time: "00:00:01:999"},
  {student_code: "AAA-001-6Yj8", questions: "Weight (in kg)", answer: "34", time: "00:00:04:969"}
];

const groupBy = (array, key) => {
  return array.reduce((result, currentValue) => {
    (result[currentValue[key]] = result[currentValue[key]] || []).push(
      currentValue
    );
    return result;
  }, {});
};

const groupedValue = groupBy(inputValue, 'student_code');
const result = Object.entries(groupedValue).map((item) => ({
  student_code: item[0],
  questions: item[1]
}));

console.log(result); // Will show what you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a map first and then create an array using the keys from the map.

```js
// Assume the data variable is your existing array of objects 
const data = [
  {student_code: "AAA-001-ZYrq", questions: "Height (in cm)", answer: "4543435", time: "00:00:07:00"},
  {student_code: "AAA-001-6Yj8", questions: "Height (in cm)", answer: "4334", time: "00:00:02:32"},
  {student_code: "AAA-001-ZYrq", questions: "Weight (in kg)", answer: "2345", time: "00:00:01:999"},
  {student_code: "AAA-001-6Yj8", questions: "Weight (in kg)", answer: "34", time: "00:00:04:969"}
];

const codeMap = {};

for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    const entry = data[i];

    // Initialize an empty array for this student code if not already
    if(! codeMap[entry.student_code] ){
        codeMap[entry.student_code] = [];
    }

    codeMap[entry.student_code].push({
        question: entry.questions, 
        answer: entry.answer,
        time: entry.time
    })

}

// Now that you've created a map, you can turn it into an array 

const reducedArray = [];

const studentCodes = Object.keys(codeMap);

for(let x = 0 ; x < studentCodes.length; x++){
    const code = studentCodes[x];
    reducedArray.push({
        student_code: code,
        questions: codeMap[code]
    });

}

// Now the reducedArray variable should have what you want
console.log(reducedArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'd do it. Just my two cents.

```js
const data = [
  {student_code: "AAA-001-ZYrq", questions: "Height (in cm)", answer: "4543435", time: "00:00:07:00"},
  {student_code: "AAA-001-6Yj8", questions: "Height (in cm)", answer: "4334", time: "00:00:02:32"},
  {student_code: "AAA-001-ZYrq", questions: "Weight (in kg)", answer: "2345", time: "00:00:01:999"},
  {student_code: "AAA-001-6Yj8", questions: "Weight (in kg)", answer: "34", time: "00:00:04:969"}
];

//build a datum(s) by code lookup
const datumsByCode = {};
for (let datum of data) {
  const code = datum.student_code;
  datumsByCode[code] = datumsByCode[code] || [];
  datumsByCode[code].push(datum);
}

const newData = [];
for (let code in datumsByCode) {
  const datums = datumsByCode[code];
  const newDatum = {
    student_code: code,
    questions: datums.map(datum => ({
      question: datum.questions,
      answer: datum.answer,
      time: datum.time
    }))
  };
  newData.push(newDatum);
}

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score -1):

arr is your array object you mentioned,

```
const result = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
  if (a.some(el => el.student_code === c.student_code)) {
    let index = a.map(el => el.student_code).indexOf(c.student_code);
    a[index].questions.push({
      question: c.questions,
      answer: c.asnwer,
      time: c.time
    });
  } else {
    a.push({
      student_code: c.student_code,
      questions: [{ question: c.questions, answer: c.asnwer, time: c.time }]
    });
  }
  return a;
}, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

use Array reduce method

```js
let arr = [{
    student_code: "AAA-001-ZYrq",
    questions: "Height (in cm)",
    answer: "4543435",
    time: "00:00:07:00"
  },
  {
    student_code: "AAA-001-6Yj8",
    questions: "Height (in cm)",
    answer: "4334",
    time: "00:00:02:32"
  },
  {
    student_code: "AAA-001-ZYrq",
    questions: "Weight (in kg)",
    answer: "2345",
    time: "00:00:01:999"
  },
  {
    student_code: "AAA-001-6Yj8",
    questions: "Weight (in kg)",
    answer: "34",
    time: "00:00:04:969"
  }
]

let result = arr.reduce((a, c) => {

  let std = a.find(e => e.student_code == c.student_code);

  if (!std) {
    std = {
      student_code: c.student_code,
      questions: []
    }

    a.push(std);
  }

  std.questions.push({
    question: c.questions,
    answer: c.answer,
    time: c.time
  });

  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```